# How to use autopoolrelease in swift

Tags: swift, nsautoreleasepool

The use of `autoreleasepool{}` in swift is as follows.

```
autoreleasepool {
    // all usage here
}
```

But I do not know how to use it in public.

Example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    autoreleasepool {
        var results: Results<Item>!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        .....  
    }
}
```

If this is public, an error occurs. Does `autoreleasepool{}` need to be in func only?

Comment: _Does auautoreleasepool{} need to be in func only?_ Approximately YES. More precisely, `autoreleasepool{}` is a function call in Swift and it needs to be placed where you can write a function call. I do not understand what you mean by _public_, but if you can explain what you really want to do more clearly, there are many who can show you the right usage of `autoreleasepool{}`.

Comment: Correct, `autoreleasepool` only makes sense inside function. But why, precisely, are you trying to use `autoreleasepool` at all? It only is useful in rare cases, e.g. when instantiating a lot of Objective-C autorelease objects within a long loop and you want to reduce peak memory usage. But it offers no value for Swift objects (and not even with all Objective-C objects; only autorelease ones). So why are you using it here? I suspect you misunderstand its purpose.

Comment: I am a starter. Thank you for your understanding. I am studying Realm. I am practicing the use of autopoolrelease when deleting a Realm DataBase file from Realm. It says that autopoolrelease should be used when deleting files from Realm. So it is easy to do in func, but I am thinking about how to remove the remnants of realm in public.

Comment: The Realm documentation is pretty clear that they want you to wrap your Realm code in `autoreleasepool` blocks, so go ahead and do as they've shown. But you don't wrap your property declarations. It's just for code inside a method or closure.

Comment: Yes sir. Thanks Rob